# C++ equivalent to python's itertools::cycle

Tags: c++, containers, cycle

Is there a C++ class (or libboost class) similar to python's itertools::cycle ?

I am looking for a container class that I can "roll" or "shift in a cycle". Example with integers :

```
MyCont = {{1,2,3}}
MyCont.roll()  // MyCont now holds {{2,3,1}}
cout << MyCont[0] << endl; // returns 2
cout << MyCont[1] << endl; // returns 3
```

Do I need to implement it myself, or is there an existing implementation somewhere ?

### Edit

The above example demonstrates the behaviour I am looking for, but my case is slightly more difficult : my container holds objects, each of them embedding a large array. I want to reorder the container's items without performing deep copies. What is the best way to do so ?

Comment: It would surprise me, honestly, if it was even included in a 3rd party C++ library like boost. It seems a sufficiently trivial operation.

Comment: Indeed, there are more complex operations than this one, but still, it would be a shame to put effort into something that has already been done by someone else. Besides, if I implement it myself I am not 100% sure I would be smart enough to figure out the best implementation from the first try.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is [`rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) in algorithms.

For your updated issue you are correct in thinking to hold pointers to the objects in an array and rotate them.  Or you could try [`list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and use the internal [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/swap) method which "Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements." or the specialisation of [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/swap2) for lists

Comment: I just realised there is a drawback in using std::rotate : in my application, the container holds objects that embed each one large array. Yet, g++'s std::rotate() calls std::swap() which uses the calling object's copy constructor. In my application, deep copies should be prevented where possible. Initially, I was thinking about using pointers (or similar) to reorder the container's items without performing deep copies, but perhaps there is a different (better) solution. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try a ptr container (from boost) if you don't want to manage memory yourself.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling unfortunately I made a custom implementation this time but I'll consider your suggestion if I encounter a similar need in the future. Thanks for the tip !